# Apollo-client updates cache after mutation, but doesn't update page

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-client, mutation

I am doing a very simple mutation which adds items to a single list of items, I can see that after the mutation it is successfully added into the cache:

[image]

However the page does not update with the new data.

## Query

```
export const RAW_CONFIG = `
  {
    allAdminConfigCategories {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          dateCreated
          dateEdited
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

## Component

```
<Query fetchPolicy="cache-and-network" query={CONFIG}>
  {({ data: { allAdminConfigCategories } }) => {
    const items = allAdminConfigCategories ? allAdminConfigCategories.edges.map(item => item.nodes) : []
    return (
      <Container data={allAdminConfigCategories} testId="admin-config">
        <Mutation mutation={CREATE}>
          {mutation => {
            return <Form submit={mutation} trigger={<CreateButton />} />
          }}
        </Mutation>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {allAdminConfigCategories.map(item => (
             <h1>{item.name}</h1>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Container>
    )
  }}
</Query>
```

## Mutation - createItem

I have included all the possible returnable data in a hope to see which one works. My understanding is, if there is an id it will do the check for this against the cache.

```
export const CREATE = gql`
  mutation createAdminConfigCategory($name: String!) {
    createAdminConfigCategory(input: { adminConfigCategory: { name: $name } }) {
      adminConfigCategory {
        id
        name
        dateCreated
        dateEdited
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Comment: By any chance could it be your Container component that is not re-rendering, if you try to check the items variable, does it update? Unfortunately, there's too few context, and really a lot of things can be happening. I recommend you switching for @apollo/react-hooks, by the way.

Comment: Missed this comment. I will certainly have a little play with this, I am not sure it would be, but I will check